# Hidden phone number can't be scraped

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've been having trouble trying to extract the phone number after clicking the "llamar" button. So far I've used the xpath method with selenium and also tried using beautiful soup to extract the number but unfortunately nothing has worked. I usually get an invalid selector error (if I use an xpath selector with selenium) and with BS4 I get a - AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text' ...
I hope you can help me out!

Here is the url to the link - https://www.milanuncios.com/venta-de-pisos-en-malaga-malaga/portada-alta-carlos-de-haya-carranque-386352344.htm

Heres the code that I tried:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import UnexpectedAlertPresentException

url = 'https://www.milanuncios.com/venta-de-pisos-en-malaga-malaga/portada-alta-carlos-de-haya-carranque - 386352344.htm'
path = r'C:\Users\WL-133\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\chromedriver.exe'
path1 = r'C:\Users\WL-133\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox'
# driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)
options = Options()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)
driver.get(url)

a = []

mah_div = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(mah_div, features='lxml')

cookie_button = '//*[@id="sui-TcfFirstLayerModal"]/div/div/footer/div/button[2]'
btn_press = driver.find_element_by_xpath(cookie_button)
btn_press.click()

llam_button = '//*[@id="ad-detail-contact"]/a[2]'
llam_press = driver.find_element_by_xpath(llam_button)
llam_press.click()
time.sleep(10)

for item in soup.find_all("div", {"class": "contenido"}):
    a.append(item.find("div", {"class": "plaincontenido"}).text)

print(a)
```

Comment: Use this `soup.select_one("script[type='application/ld+json']:contains('Product')").get_text(strip=True)` to parse relevant script tag and then scoop out the value of `description` which contains the phone number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With **Selenium** you will need to click the button and to switch to iframe.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
            (By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".def-btn.phone-btn")))
tel_button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".def-btn.phone-btn")
tel_button.click()
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, "ifrw")))
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".texto>.telefonos")))
tel_number = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".texto>.telefonos").text
```

Please note, I used much stable locators.

Comment: Incredible! Works perfectly thanks. I also just learnt about the need to switch frames for situations like these. This is going to be very useful for future web scrapes.

Answer (score 1):

The phone is stored inside Javascript. You can use `re` module to extract it:

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.milanuncios.com/venta-de-pisos-en-malaga-malaga/portada-alta-carlos-de-haya-carranque-386352344.htm"
phone_url = "https://www.milanuncios.com/datos-contacto/?usePhoneProxy=0&from=detail&includeEmail=false&id={}"

ad_id = re.search(r"(\d+)\.htm", url).group(1)

html_text = requests.get(phone_url.format(ad_id)).text

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, "html.parser")
phone = re.search(r"getTrackingPhone\((.*?)\)", html_text).group(1)

print(soup.select_one(".texto").get_text(strip=True), phone)
```

Prints:

```
ana (Particular) 639....
```