# Python - webCrawler - driver.close incorrect syntax

Tags: python, selenium, syntax, web-crawler

Novice programmer, currently making a `WebCrawler` and came up with
`driver.close()`

^incorrect syntax as shown below,

However, I used driver above with no problem so I'm pretty perplexed at the moment

I appreciate all the help I can get

thanks in advance team

```
    import sys
    from selenium import webdriver as wd
    # from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
    
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    # import pymysql as my
    import time
    # from Tour import TourInfo
    
    
    # First Url =
    # https://stamprally.org/?search_keywords=&search_keywords_operator=and&search_cat1=145&search_cat2=0
    
    # Second Url =
    # https://stamprally.org/?search_keywords=&search_keywords_operator=and&search_cat1=66&search_cat2=0
    
    
    driver.get(main_url)
    
    
    
    try:
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            # 지정한 요소 한개가 발견되면 웨이트 종료
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'header_search_cat1'))
        )
    except Exception as e:
        print('오류 발생', e)
    
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    
    for prefectureValue in range(66, 121):
        offshorePrefectureValue = 145
        try:
            driver.get(
                f"https://stamprally.org/?search_keywords=&search_keywords_operator=and&search_cat1={prefectureValue}&search_cat2=0)")
            print(driver.current_url)
    
    # close  off
        driver.close()
        driver.quit()
        sys.exit()
```

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
PS C:\Users\eong\Desktop\stamprally_crawl> python run.py
  File "C:\Users\eong\Desktop\stamprally_crawl\run.py", line 70
    driver.close()
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this from loop (indentation problem). I think the is the main mistake.

```
driver.close()
driver.quit()
sys.exit()
```

It quits driver after the first cycle in your loop.
Ream here about the difference between `quit()` and `close()`: [Difference between webdriver.Dispose(), .Close() and .Quit()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15067107/difference-between-webdriver-dispose-close-and-quit)
Additionally, put `break` if your conditions becomes correct.
Also, you declare `offshorePrefectureValue` but do not really use it.
Another problem does not relate to your question:

```
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        # 지정한 요소 한개가 발견되면 웨이트 종료
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'header_search_cat1'))
    )
except Exception as e:
    print('오류 발생', e)
```

You do not need `try/except` here as well. Selenium will throw exception if an element is not present.

Comment: Valid points thanks @vitaliis

I changed my code as below, 

'''

for prefectureValue in list(range(66, 121))+[145]:
    try:
        driver.get(
            f"https://stamprally.org/?search_keywords=&search_keywords_operator=and&search_cat1={prefectureValue}&search_cat2=0)")
        print(driver.current_url)
    except Exception as e:
        print('오류 발생', e)

'''

Best, feel free to let me know if you see anything off cheers mate

Comment: You can also check here how to use explicit wait in Selenium https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67082774/hidden-phone-number-cant-be-scraped/67082898#67082898 You will need it later for sure

Answer (score 1):

In case you opened single window only you have nothing to `driver.quit()` from after performing `driver.close()`

Comment: thanks for the input. I'll take that into consideration. Though it still does not solve the syntax error. this is a true mind duming moment for me

Comment: Could you share the syntax error you receiving inside your question?

Comment: I would also say that you are trying to quit/close the driver in loop i.e several times while you initialized it only once in the beginning however I do not think this is a syntax error.

Comment: i'm curious if you are also getting the same syntax error, thanks alot for the help really appreciating it

Comment: I even do not have python installed on my PC today :)

Answer (score 0):

A try needs to have a except (or finally) block as well. So either remove the try, or add an except  to catch the error.

Cant believe i spent so much time looking for syntax when i missed the bloody catchException code thinking that i do not need exception catch because i know this would not error out